# What details to keep in mind when distributing my application?

Tags: windows, vb.net

On Windows 7, VB.NET Express, I have developed a simple Forms application. I don't really make use of any external plugins or anything - it just has a couple buttons, pictureboxes, GDI operations to modify some images...

And now it is complete. And I would like to already upload it. But, since this is actually the first time I try to submit something, *what other details should I keep in mind when distributing my application?* I mean stuff like... *will my application work as expected in other machines? Other Windows versions?* I am not in a proper position to test it in other machines, I fear, so I am relying the "default" settings and hoping it will simply work.

Comment: There is no substitute for exhaustive testing. Set up virtual machines if you don't have physical equipment handy for testing purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you use platform-specific APIs (which are rare in your typical, garden-variety .NET application) then it should work on all versions of Windows that support your version of the .NET Framework. If the end user *doesn't* have that version of the .NET Framework installed, then he or she will need to get it manually. You can make that a little easier by using the built-in ClickOnce installer (Build > Publish <project name>) if you're not already using it.

Apart from that, no, there shouldn't be any problems, given that you say your application is a simple one. (And console applications can even work on Linux and Mac using Mono!)

Comment: I haven't used the One-Click installer. Let me see... it gives me a folder with three items in it. I assume I have to distribute this whole folder, right? And I guess the user has to run the "setup" file... and it works. Great. But wait: the installation says "**From:** Users/Me/Desktop/MyProgram..." that a path in my computer! Will the end-user see that? What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: Yup, you have to distribute the whole folder - that is, if you chose to distribute it on a CD or network share. There's also a web-based installer. And no, the path is just telling the user where the software is being installed from (for security) - your computer's path won't show up on their computer, don't worry.

Comment: What will the path be in the eyes of the user? Can't he choose the path anyway? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Omega: It'll just be wherever `setup.exe` is located. Yes, the user can choose the path - I'm not sure what the reasoning was, really. But it works :)